# Conditions in Where Clauses based on a flag

Tags: sql, t-sql

Can I use a flag to select different WHERE clause? Something like this.

```
SELECT  fields
 from T3 t3 
left outer join T1 t1 on T1.Id=t2.Id
WHERE 
    CASE 
        WHEN @Status <> 1 
        THEN (t3.Id = @SId AND sh.StatusId = 3 AND k.StatusId = 1)
        ELSE t2.Id = @SID AND  t2.StatusID = 12
GROUP BY whatever
```

Comment: you are selecting from T3 and joining T1 where T1=T2 but you are not joining on T2 anywhere?  are you missing code?

Comment: Yeah!! sorry about the typo. I am doing the same but getting an Parse error. Incorrect syntax near '='. at WHERE statement..

Comment: are you joining on T2 in your query?  if so can you edit the question and post the full query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preferred way:

```
    WHERE
    (@Status <> 1 AND t3.Id = @SId AND sh.StatusId = 3 AND k.StatusId = 1)
    OR (t2.Id = @SID AND t2.StatusID = 12)
```

or this is a little easier to read case statement:

```
WHERE
CASE WHEN @Status <> 1 
       AND t3.Id = @SId 
       AND sh.StatusId = 3 
       AND k.StatusId = 1 THEN 1
WHEN t2.Id = @SID 
       AND t2.StatusID = 12 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Comment: @user424134: I don't think either of these `WHERE` clauses follows the logic in the question and both result in 'false positive' errors. See my answer.

Comment: @onedaywhen I agree that my answer does not match his original, but he was struggling with the original and I think that this is probably what he wants logically. If not, writing it clearer will help get him  to the correct logic.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need CASE WHEN? Can you just do WHERE Status <> 1 AND ... OR ...?

Answer (score 1):

You can - just add an `END` to the `CASE`.

```
SELECT  fields
FROM    T3 t3 
LEFT OUTER JOIN T1 t1 on T1.Id=t2.Id
WHERE 
        CASE 
          WHEN @Status <> 1 THEN 
            (t3.Id = @SId AND sh.StatusId = 3 AND k.StatusId = 1)
           ELSE 
            t2.Id = @SID AND  t2.StatusID = 12
        END
GROUP BY whatever
```

Comment: It dosent work with END either.. Getting an Parser error in WHERE statement. Incorrect syntax near '='

Comment: The query is not complete - the alias `t2` wont resolve. I just copied your code and add the `END` to explain the necessary syntax change.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  `CASE` returns a value, so the usage would be something like:

```
where case
  when @Mode = 1 and A.Foo = B.Foo then 1
  when @Mode = 2 and A.Foo > B.Foo + 5 then 1
  when A.Bar < @Mode then 1
  else 0
  end = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think @JBrooks has properly translated your case statement (and, worryingly, can result in false positives).

I think the `CASE` equivalent is as follows:

```
WHERE 1 = CASE 
             WHEN @Status <> 1 
             THEN CASE 
                     WHEN (t3.Id = @SID AND sh.StatusId = 3 AND k.StatusId = 1) 
                     THEN 1 
                  END
             ELSE CASE 
                     WHEN t2.Id = @SID AND t2.StatusID = 12 
                     THEN 1 
                  END 
          END
```

I do, however, agree that such a construct is hard to read and debug and agree that it can be transformed. However, while @JBrooks's "preferred way" is disjunctive normal form (i.e. `(predicate_1 OR predicate_2)` which requires parens), I prefer conjunctive normal form (i.e. `preidcate_1 AND preidcate_2`) e.g.

```
WHERE
( p.Status = 1 OR ( t3.Id = p.SID AND sh.StatusId = 3 AND k.StatusId = 1 ) )
AND
( p.Status <> 1 OR ( t2.Id = p.SID AND t2.StatusID = 12 ) )
```